# Logstash not reading in new entries from MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have Logstash and Elasticsearch installed locally on my Windows 7 machine.
I installed [logstash-input-jdbc](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc) in Logstash.

I have data in MySql database which I send to Elasticsearch using Logstash so I can do some report generating.

Logstash config file that does this.

```
input {
 jdbc {
   jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
   jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
   jdbc_user => "root"
   jdbc_password => ""
   statement => "SELECT * FROM transport.audit"
   jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
   jdbc_page_size => "50000"
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "transport-audit-%{+YYYY.mm.dd}"
}
}
```

this works and Logstash sends the data to Elasticsearch when I run :

```
bin\logstash agent -f \logstash\conf\01_input.conf
```

this is the response from that command

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Default settings used: Filter workers: 4
Logstash startup completed
Logstash shutdown completed
```

WHY, does Logstash shutdown?

when I check Elasticsearch the data is there, and if I run the command again the data is re-indexed (duplicated).

[image]

Here is the Mysql data:

[image]

What I am trying to do (achieve):

I want Logstash to run and listen for new entries on audit table and only index that data (when a new audit entry is entered into the table Logstash would know and send that entry to Elasticsearch.

Also why does Logstash stop when I run that command, should it not be running? I am new to Logstash and Elasticsearch.

Thanks

G

I have also posted the same question in [Elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-to-listen-for-new-entries-from-mysql/34018), and if I get the answer I will post here to help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the logstash-input-jdbc plugin will run your SELECT statement once and then quit. You can change this behavior by adding a [`schedule` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_usage) with a cron expression to your configuration, like this:

```
input {
 jdbc {
   jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
   jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
   jdbc_user => "root"
   jdbc_password => ""
   statement => "SELECT * FROM transport.audit"
   schedule => "* * * * *"               <----- add this line
   jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
   jdbc_page_size => "50000"
 }
}
```

The result is that the SELECT statement will now run every minute.

If you had a date field in your MySQL table (but it doesn't seem the case), you could also use the pre-defined `sql_last_start` parameter in order to not re-index all records on every run. That parameter can be used in your query like this:

```
   statement => "SELECT * FROM transport.audit WHERE your_date_field >= :sql_last_start"
```

Comment: Thanks @val for your help and edit, I will try this today and mark the question as answered. Yes I agree with the date field and will add as advised.

Comment: The schedule works fine thanks with the select statement, I recreated the table, added a timestamp field.  When I add the WHERE clause nothing is printed out or sent to elasticsearch? `code statement => "SELECT * FROM transport.audit WHERE timestamp >= :sql_last_start" `

Comment: What value did you set for the new timestamp field?

Comment: creating table `code timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ` and value entered `code 2015-11-09 10:17:46` . Do I need to set `code :sql_last_start` as a parameter before I use it?

Comment: Probably that `sql_last_start` was not set on the first run. Maybe run it without the WHERE clause once so it loads everything and sets the `sql_last_start` date, and then add the WHERE clause back.