# Stopping pipeline in logstash

Tags: docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch, logstash

A line of error code print out when I am trying to run logstash in docker

Here is the error code:

```
[LogStash::Runner] WARN  logstash.agent - stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Below is my configuration when running logstash in docker

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/config-dir/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.5:3306/data1"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    statement => "SELECT * from COMPANY"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "172.17.0.2:9200"
  "index" => "test-migrate"
  "document_type" => "data"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning indicating that your pipeline is shutting down. This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591537/4604579

Comment: It works !!! Thank you very much