# Logstash with JDBC pipeline deployed on Docker stack creates new containers repeatedly

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have been trying to teach myself how to deploy ELK on Docker in my local machine, the following problem has been occuring for a week now and I have not been able to find a solution online.

I run "docker deploy -c docker-compose.yml elk_stack" on the following configuration.
The problem I am facing is, after the logstash container is created, the logs show the pipeline configuration was correctly picked and the data flows through to the elasticsearch container. Then once all the data has been moved, the logstash container destroys itself and a new container is created which follows the same steps as the last one.

Why is this the case?

The following is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
networks:
  elk_net:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - elk_net
    depends_on:
      - elk_net
      - mysqldata
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - elk_net
    depends_on:
      - elk_net
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elk_net
    depends_on:
      - elk_net
  logstash:
    image: logstash:custom
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes: 
      - ./dependency:/usr/local/dependency/
      - ./logstash/pipeline/mysql:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
    networks:
      - elk_net
    depends_on:
      - elk_net
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - elk_net
    depends_on:
      - elk_net

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

Here is my logstash conf

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sonar_data"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        jdbc_driver_library => ""
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        tracking_column => "accounting_entry_id"
        tracking_column_type => "numeric"
        use_column_value => true
        statement => "SELECT * FROM call_detail_record WHERE accounting_entry_id > :sql_last_value ORDER BY accounting_entry_id ASC"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "cdr_data"
    }
}
```

Sample of the docker logs:

```
ravi@ravi-VirtualBox:~/Documents/git_personal/cdr-data-visualizer-elk$ sudo docker logs 2c89502d48b3 -f
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.7.0.jar) to field java.io.FileDescriptor.fd
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-09-17T08:06:56,317][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2019-09-17T08:06:56,339][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2019-09-17T08:06:56,968][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.3.1"}
[2019-09-17T08:06:57,002][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"7a2b2d2a-157e-42c3-bcde-a14dc773750f", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2019-09-17T08:06:57,795][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,033][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,316][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,391][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,393][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,720][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
[2019-09-17T08:06:59,725][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,244][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 59 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 19 keys and 39 values 
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,818][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,842][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,860][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,868][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:07:01,930][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2019-09-17T08:07:02,138][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using default mapping template
[2019-09-17T08:07:02,328][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been create for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2019-09-17T08:07:02,332][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2228b784 run>"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:02,439][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2019-09-17T08:07:02,947][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:03,178][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,327][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch bulk_path=>"/_monitoring/bulk?system_id=logstash&system_api_version=7&interval=1s", hosts=>[http://elasticsearch:9200], sniffing=>false, manage_template=>false, id=>"7d7dfa0f023f65240aeb31ebb353da5a42dc782979a2bd7e26e28b7cbd509bb3", document_type=>"%{[@metadata][document_type]}", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_151a6660-4b00-4b2c-8a78-3d93f5161cbe", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>"auto", ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,499][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,529][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,550][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,560][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,596][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,637][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x736c74cd run>"}
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,892][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:04,920][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:".monitoring-logstash", :main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-09-17T08:07:05,660][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-09-17T08:07:06,850][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.029802s) SELECT version()
[2019-09-17T08:07:07,038][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.007399s) SELECT version()
[2019-09-17T08:07:07,393][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.003612s) SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM (SELECT * FROM call_detail_record WHERE accounting_entry_id > 0 ORDER BY accounting_entry_id ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 1
[2019-09-17T08:07:07,545][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.041288s) SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM call_detail_record WHERE accounting_entry_id > 0 ORDER BY accounting_entry_id ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 0
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
************ A LOT OFF RECORDS ARE PUSHED TO ELASTICSEARCH FROM MYSQL SUCCESSFULLY******************
....

[2019-09-17T08:07:13,148][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2019-09-17T08:07:13,633][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
ravi@ravi-VirtualBox:~/Documents/git_personal/cdr-data-visualizer-elk$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an annoying issue but I found the answer after a lot of trial and error.

My issue was that I did not have the schedule CRON expression configured in my logstash pipeline config.

Adding the following line to the config did the trick.

```
schedule => "*/10 * * * *"
```

This post helped me out.
[Logstash not reading in new entries from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571490/logstash-not-reading-in-new-entries-from-mysql)