# Logstash to elasticsearch data not getting indexed when trying to add an id in config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using `logstash` to add indexes to my `elastic seach` by pulling data from my `Oracle DB` and my logstash config is as follows:

```
input {

 jdbc
{

    jdbc_driver_library => "<path>/ojdbc10.jar"

    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

    jdbc_connection_string => "connection string"

    jdbc_user => <username>

    jdbc_password => <pwd>

    statement => "SELECT * FROM my table name"

}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "test1"
  }
```

And I see the below result:

```
curl http://<ip>:9200/_cat/indices?v
health status index uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   test1 596HT2HTRyyNl79GdiXvvw   1   1    5186122            0    799.4mb        799.4mb
```

This is working fine and I am able to load data. But now when I try to add an Id to my index so that I can prevent duplicate enties, with following config:

```
input {

 jdbc
{

    jdbc_driver_library => "<path>/ojdbc10.jar"

    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

    jdbc_connection_string => "connection string"

    jdbc_user => <username>

    jdbc_password => <pwd>

    statement => "SELECT * FROM my table name"

}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "test4"
    action => "update"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{col1}%-%{col2}%"
  }
```

And now when I query indexes:

```
curl http://<ip>:9200/_cat/indices?v
health status index uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
ellow open   test4 PhkmuzRPTPCplaxQGNaelw   1   1          1       149711     31.2mb         31.2mb
```

Not sure what I am missing here. I want to aviod duplicates and also want to be able to capture delta on that table. My table has a `composite key` which I am trying to combine as id for the elastic search index here.

Comment: How do the IDs in your elasticsearch documents look like? Can you show a sample document?

Comment: @Val with or without setting the doc id. When I set doc id, data is not getting inserted

Comment: For one, the syntax is wrong, it should be `"%{col1}-%{col2}"`

Comment: @val that fixed my problem. So looks like whenever I run logstash, its reindexing the whole table. Its matching the count of rows in DB. Is this the right aproach ? Also any way to keep running this periodically, since the logstash is shuttinng down after one execution

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591537/4604579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to follow the link shared be @Val https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591537/4604579 updated my configs and I am able to index the document as required

My Updated config is:

```
input {

 jdbc
{

    jdbc_driver_library => "<path>/ojdbc10.jar"

    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

    jdbc_connection_string => "connection string"

    jdbc_user => <username>

    jdbc_password => <pwd>

    statement => "SELECT * FROM my table name WHERE last_modified_date >= :sql_last_value"

    schedule => "* * * * *"
"

}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "test2"
        document_id => "%{col1}-%{col2}-%{col3}"
        action => "update"
      doc_as_upsert => true
      document_id => "%{col1}-%{col2}-%{col3}"


  }
```

Comment: @Val is it possible to use the above config to run delta every 3 hours and a fultruth at specified time everyday without having a conflict?